# A way to use textbf and textit at the same time with one command

Tags: text-manipulation, keycommand

Hello I have to make a document where I use a lot \textbf and \textit at the same time, so I tried to create a new command where it use both at the same time, but it gave me an error and I don't know how to do this in the correct way, I used:

```
\newcommand{\bfit}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
```

Any idea how to make this?

Edit: The error that appears is this (I am on Texstudio):
[image]

Comment: This should work fine (if \bfit is not already defined). What error do you get?

Comment: I edited the question with the error

Comment: Sounds as if you are missing a closing brace somewhere.

Comment: Can you please post a MCVE? That will help locate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine in WinEdt with MikTeX. Here is a MWE for reference:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\bfit}[1]{\textbf{\textit{#1}}}
\begin{document}
  \textbf{\textit{Hello World}} \par
  \bfit{Using new command}
\end{document}
```

[image]